# How can I invest in US Stocks from outside the US with a credit card instead of a bank account?

Tags: credit-card, stocks, international

I would like to know if it it possible to invest, buy stock, for example in [Apple](http://www.google.com/finance?client=ob&q=NASDAQ%3aAAPL) from outside the US.

I  would not like to use bank accounts in possible rather the credit card, to do this, what would be a **simple** way (no real previous experience in this).

Also, what would be the minimum amount (I'm not willing to try with huge sums of money)

Of course by all means this should be safe.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Perhaps you should just get a separate bank account and transfer only the money you want to invest to that account. Then the rest of your accounts are still safe.

Comment: I seriously doubt if any sane broker/merchant will allow you to trade with your credit card.

Answer (score 2):

You'll have to take cash from your Credit Card account and use that to trade. I doubt any brokerage house will take credit cards as it's trading without any collateral (since credit cards are an unsecured credit)

Comment: Ok I get it, but I though there might be an online system to which I can pay and then invest my money?

Comment: Credit cards also hit the merchant with a fee of around 3% per transaction. If you're a retailer who appreciates the convenience it brings your customers, that's one thing, but if you're in the business of trading cash for securities it ain't gonna fly.